# Is it possible to create a catkin package to provide precompiled libraries?

Tags: ros, catkin, libraries, catkin-package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a way to create a catkin package that only provides precompiled libraries instead of building them, so that other catkin packages can depend on them and the libraries are present in the devel folder when the other packages are build?

Greetings, Thiemo

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/66685/is-it-possible-to-create-a-catkin-package-to-provide-precompiled-libraries?/) by [Thiemo](https://answers.ros.org/users/5332/thiemo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2013-07-05

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-07-05**:
Why pre-compiled libraries? For what architecture? Do you not have the sources?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The question is better framed "is there a way to do this with CMake". catkin doesn't make any restrictions on this, but it also does not provide specific infrastructure to support it.

Distributing precompiled binaries is bad because it basically limits the package's availability to select platforms and architectures. That being said maybe you can look at the `prosilica_gige_sdk`:

https://github.com/ros-drivers/prosilica_gige_sdk

This package distributes binaries for several architectures.

You'll also want to review the legal consequences for distributing binaries which you got from somewhere else with do not provide the source code. If they do provide source code I highly advise you to use that instead.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2013-07-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Thiemo](https://answers.ros.org/users/5332/thiemo/) on 2013-07-07**:
Thanks for the answer. I looked into it and I will try to adapt it.

Answer (score 0):

The answer above and other related resources helped me find out the following solution. My main problem was that the libraries wouldn't be seen in the devel space, which I brute-force solved by copying them.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(my_project)

set(include_directories ${put_all_your_libraries_public_include_directories_here})
set(libraries ${put_all_your_libraries_absolute_paths_here})

find_package(catkin REQUIRED)

catkin_package(INCLUDE_DIRS ${include_directories} LIBRARIES ${libraries})

# Required for the shared libraries to be seen in the devel space
file(COPY ${libraries} DESTINATION ${CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY})

# Required for the headers to be seen in the install space
install(
  DIRECTORY ${include_directories}
  DESTINATION ${CATKIN_GLOBAL_INCLUDE_DESTINATION}
  FILES_MATCHING
  PATTERN "*.h" # optional
  PATTERN "*.hpp") # optional

# Required for the shared libraries to be seen in the install space
install(FILES ${libraries} DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION})
```